# Completely disabling flycheck in Doom Emacs

Tags: flycheck, doom, lsp-mode

I'm setting up Doom Emacs, and I want to remove flycheck entirely. I'm having a bit of trouble doing that, though.

As an example, I'm working with Ruby, with this setup:

```lisp
(doom!
  :completion  company
  :tools       lsp
  :lang        (ruby +rails +rbenv +lsp)
  ;; etc.
  )
```

So far I have:

1. disabled the `:checkers syntax` module from my `init.el`
2. disabled the flycheck package in my `packages.el`

   ```lisp
   (package! flycheck :disable t)
   ```
3. turned off a number of [related `lsp-mode` features](https://emacs-lsp.github.io/lsp-mode/tutorials/how-to-turn-off/)

   ```lisp
   (setq-hook! lsp
     lsp-diagnostics-provider :none
     lsp-ui-sideline-enable nil
     lsp-modeline-diagnostics-enable nil
     lsp-modeline-diagnostics-enable nil
     lsp-signature-render-documentation nil
     lsp-enable-symbol-highlighting nil
     lsp-headerline-breadcrumb-enable nil)
   ```

With all of that in place, flycheck initially *seems* deactivated. However, after a file has been open for some amount of time, it appears that LSP is reactivating flycheck, including bringing back all of the squiggly underlines, the modeline "diagnostics," etc.

When I remove all references to `lsp` from my `init.el`, then indeed flycheck goes away entirely—but, of course, that's not ideal, as I'd like to use LSP.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out—it turns out that `setq-hook!` sets the variables in the wrong scope. When I switched to a more general `use-package!` declaration for LSP, it started working perfectly.

```lisp
(use-package! lsp-mode
  ;; Need to repeat this line from the Doom lsp module
  ;; declaration to keep it from eager-loading:
  :commands lsp-install-server

  :config
  (setq lsp-diagnostics-provider :none
        lsp-ui-sideline-enable nil
        lsp-modeline-diagnostics-enable nil
        ;; etc.
        ))
```

Comment: Could this applied for the normal emacs?

Comment: @alper This syntax comes from [use-package](https://jwiegley.github.io/use-package/), which you can certainly use in vanilla Emacs. (Note that `use-package!` is a Doom-specific wrapper—normally you'd just call it with `use-package`.) Otherwise, just put the `(setq ...)` expression where you put your [other lsp-mode setup](https://emacs-lsp.github.io/lsp-mode/page/installation/).